# Function to report all polygons and their data within another polygons?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, statistics, union, reports

I have a layer with different types of vegetation and another layer with estates. Is there a function in ArcGIS 10.3 to create a report of each estate where it lists what It finds on a selected estate?

It is worth mentioning that I have already used union to cookie cut the "nature polygons" to the estate, which means there can be cases where there are 3-4 different nature types on a estate which a lot of information assosiated to each of them

Answer (score 1):

To do this try using [Union](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/union.htm) which:

> Computes a geometric union of the input features. All features and
>   their attributes will be written to the output feature class.

followed by [Summary Statistics](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/summary-statistics.htm) which:

> Calculates summary statistics for field(s) in a table.

You would use the identifier field from one of the original layers as the case item to summarize information from the other.